# iterate through the fields of each object of a linked list

Tags: java

Below I have got a class with two int variables from which I have created a number of objects which I have stored in the linked list. Now I want to loop through each object and compare THEIR FIELDS from the class with other int values. In other words I want to loop through the fields of the objects and not the objects themselves. Any help?

```
 import java.util.*;
  import java.io.*;


 public class Obj 
 {
 int n;
 int c;

public Obj (int nn)
 {
  n = nn;
  c = 0;  
 }


 public static void main(String argv[]) throws IOException
 {

  LinkedList list = new LinkedList();   

  int i = 7;
  Obj element = new Obj(i);
  // I may add further objects..

 list.add(element);

 // then I want to iterate through the linked list of objects and get each object
 // and compare its n or c field values with something else

 // It should sth like the below which I found in the web but I don;t get how it works

for(Obj elementf : list) 
{
   // Process each object inside of object here.
 }

}
```

Comment: You could use Reflection and iterate over `elementf.getClass().getFields()` but this almost certainly not what you want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, use `LinkedList<Obj>` and not just a raw `LinkedList`; the compiler should be complaining about the existing code.

As for "iterating over the fields", that doesn't really make sense. Just iterate over the `Obj` objects in the list and do something inside that `for` loop with `elementf.n` and `elementf.c`.

Comment: Oh yeah. When I put LinkedList<Obj> it worked. I dont understand why and how..Sorry I am just newbie to Java. Could you please explain/send me a link/ to why just the general LinkedList won't work? Thank you